# Can't seem to achieve the same effect on my slide menu as Any.Do

Tags: objective-c, ios

I am trying to create the same type of slide-up/pull-up menu (from the bottom) as the Any.do iPhone app, but not having any success.

The issue I am running into is the app was built with storyboards so I am thinking I might have to scratch that idea and use just code.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to get rid of your storyboard to recreate this, that's what IBOutlets are for. Any way, it looks like this was made by creating a UIScrollView that takes up the entire screen. Then add a UITableView to the upper section of the scroll view. Mind you in order for this to work, you'll need to disable scrolling on the scroll view in the background.

From there you can programmatically add the other elements to the scroll view to be rendered off screen, since there are only three they can probably just be buttons. And finally, since scrolling is disabled on the background scroll view you can add an image with a UISwipeGestureRecognizer at the bottom of the screen to manually change the scroll view's content offset property.